# Editing line with sed in for loop from other file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, syntax

im new in bash,

Im trying to edit line with sed with for loop from other file.

Please tell me what i doing wrong in my small code?

Do i missing another loop?

```
#!/bin/bash

# read and taking the line needed:
for j in `cat /tmp/check.txt`; do 

# replacing the old value with and value:
sed -i "s+/tmp/old_name/+/${j}/+gi" file_destantion.txt$$ 

#giving numbers to the logs for checking
Num=j +1

# moving the changed file to .log number ( as for see that it is changed):
mv file_destantion.txt$$ file_destantion.txt$$.log$Num

#create ne source file to do the next value from /tmp/check:
cp -rp file_destantion.txt file_destantion.txt$$ 

done
```

On /tmp/check i have the info that i want to enter on each loop turn.

in /tmp/check:

```
/tmp/check70
/tmp/check70_1
/tmp/_check7007
```

- In the end this is what i want it to be like:

```
.log1 > will contain /tmp/check70
.log2 > will contain /tmp/check70_1
.log3 will contain /tmp/check7007
```

Comment: Please add a shebang and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Besides the syntax erros that the shellcheck.net will show, what are you doing? The first time `sed` is called, all lines with `/tmp/old_name/` will be replaced with the first word in `check.txt`. All other attempts with `sed` will fail, because no lines with `/tmp/old_name/` will be found.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this solution worked for me.

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
grep -v '^ *#' < /tmp/check | while IFS= read -r line ;do
cp -rp file_destantion.txt file_destantion.txt$$
sed -i "s+/tmp/old_name/+${line}/+gi" file_destantion.txt$$
(( count++ ))
mv file_destantion.txt$$ "file_destantion.txt$$.log${count}"
cp -rp file_destantion.txt file_destantion.txt$$
done
```

thank you very much @Cyrus for your guiding.